# Testing if audio devices / sound cards are currently playing?

Tags: linux, scripting, audio, devices, pulseaudio

Is there a default program where I can check if my audio devices are in silent?

**Edit:** By silence, I mean that if there is something playing on that (not just activated or opened)

Something like this:

```
if [[ device0 is silent ]] ; then
    radio $RANDOM
fi
```

**Edit 2:** What I'm trying to achieve is a script that plays radio and can keep playing when the player fails, e.g. if the internet connection goes down and the player didn't recovery, I will kill the player and start over again

Comment: Do you mean a tool to check volume level?

Comment: no, check if there is something playing or not

Comment: then the only wariant I guess is to check "Mix" in alsamixer and try to record a little from soundcard, then analize volume in recorded file. If it is larger than a treshold, you can mean that there's nothing playing. Try for example `sox`. In other case you can try `lsof|grep snd`. If there's nothing you can turn radio on.

Comment: Also asked on [Superuser](http://superuser.com/q/536498/4714)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using PulseAudio (Gnome-based Linux distributions tend to use PulseAudio, you can check if one is running with `ps -C pulseaudio`) and you want to know whether some applications are sending any data to any "sink", you could do:

```
pacmd list-sink-inputs | grep -c 'state: RUNNING'
```

Still with PulseAudio, if you want to check whether your sound output is muted, there might be simpler but you can get the "mute" status of the default "sink" using:

```
pacmd dump | awk '
  $1 == "set-sink-mute" {m[$2] = $3}
  $1 == "set-default-sink" {s = $2}
  END {print m[s]}'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm using, but this script didn't work for me. (It "returns" `no` in any situation, playing or not)

Comment: Sorry, I'd missed that part. I still don't think this is doing what's requested: if an application has the device open but isn't feeding it any data, wouldn't it give a false positive?

Comment: @Gilles, in my tests (pausing `mplayer`), it gives `State: CORKED` instead of `State: RUNNING` in that case so it would still work. If the application feeds silence data (is playing silence), then I suppose it would still show `RUNNING`, but in that case, I see no other alternative than using pamon on the monitor device of all the _sinks_ and check for silence.

Comment: I tested and it's working. Thanks @Stephane I would give you all my upvotes if I could!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you right, here an example:

Silence:

```
fuser /dev/snd/timer && echo "Something is playing" || echo "There's silence"
There's silence
```

I turn on audacious:

```
fuser /dev/snd/timer && echo "Something is playing" || echo "There's silence"
/dev/snd/timer:      47663
Something is playing
```

For OSS chande `/dev/snd/timer` to `/dev/dsp`.

This is a very dependent method.

Comment: From the my homework here ( http://linux.amazingdev.com/blog/archives/000909.html ) it seems possible that a process is holding the device but not actually play anything. Is that true? (If so, it's not  useful)

Comment: Yes, it's true. If you press "pause" or "mute" it will be so. But in this case you cannot be absolutely sure that after a couple of seconds player won't play again. Or you can combine this method & write from soundcard.

Comment: In this case I'm looking for a way to overcome the player failures, so unfortunately this won't work

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using ALSA mixer for your sound, you can use `amixer` to query information about audio devices. An audio device typically has several audio channels - or controls - each which can be muted and unmuted. For example to check if the `Master` control is muted you would do something like:

```
if amixer get Master | grep -q off; then
    # action
fi
```

Use the `set` option to perform things on the controls. See `man amixer` for more help.

Comment: Perhaps there was a little ambiguity on the question, I edited.
Unfortunatly `amixer` didn't work, I tested over 15 min with absolutely no player opened, and it is still reporting "unmuted"

Comment: This checks whether the sound channel is muted, not whether there is something playing.

Answer (score 1):

htor's answer will probably work, but it is entirely possible that "off" will appear somewhere else in the output, causing an incorrect result. Here is a more strict check using GNU awk:

```
if amixer get Master | gawk 'END{ if ( $NF != "[off]" ) { exit 1 } }'; then
    # muted
else
    # unmuted
fi
```

Comment: My `amixer`'s last line has no `$6`: “ Mono: Playback [on]”. (`amixer` version 1.0.26) Maybe `$NF` would be more portable.

Comment: @manatwork Thanks for the note, the output *looked* portable, but I guess I am easily led ;-)

Comment: This checks whether the sound channel is muted, not whether there is something playing.

Comment: @Gilles - When I posted this answer, the question did not describe that problem.